# Why does tesseract append ^L to the output

Tags: command-line, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract to OCR some text in images, e.g this one:

[image]

I have this version of tesseract on my Ubuntu 20.04:

```bsh
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.1.1
 leptonica-1.79.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.3) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.1
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.4.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.4 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.2 libzstd/1.4.4
```

Invoking it as follows:

```bsh
tesseract example.png output txt
```

However, when I open the `output.txt` file in vim, I see `^L` at the last line as follows:

[image]

What is the meaning of that character? Why it is appended at the last line? Is it possible to get rid of it?

I have looked in the man page of `tesseract`, but I can't find anything about that.

Comment: Ctrl+L is the "Form Feed" character. Normally it used to indicate the end of page or the beginning of next page.

Comment: Can you try the option `-c page_separator=""` in `tesseract` command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `tesseract` adds a new page (the ASCII "Form Feed") character to the end of the text. You can delete it using:

```
sed -i 's/^L//' output.txt
```

To enter the `^L` character in the above command, fist type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

For GNU `sed` you can simply use the following command also:

```
sed  -i 's/\x0c//' output.txt
```

---

As a more straightforward method, you can use the `-c` option as follows:

```
tesseract -c page_separator="" example.png output txt
```

so you will not have any "page separator" in the output file.

Comment: Maybe using `-c` option. take a look at this link: https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-dev/c/VsgJ9R-cTQ0

Comment: Can you try the option `-c page_separator="[PAGE SEPARATOR]"` where you can put empty string for `[PAGE SEPARATOR]`, in other words: `-c page_separator=""`?

Comment: Please note that in the command you have to separate the basename from the extension by a space to get the expected filename, e.g : `output` `txt` to get `output.txt` otherwise you will get `output.txt.txt`

Comment: Sorry. I corrected.